# Cannot hide default cordova-splash screen ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, splash-screen

I have made a custom splash screen page for my ionic app. The issue is that when I build the project for ios platform the default splash screen is still loading.

I have added following in the config.xml file:

```
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

Also in the ionViewDidEnter() of the custom Splash Screen I'm hidding the default cordova splash screen;

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   ......
 }
```

What could possibly be the issue? Every time I run the build project in xcode the cordova splash screen comes first(which should be hidden), instead of the custom one.

I have the tried the config settings from the below referrences :

[joshmorony](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/)

[coursetro](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/51/How-to-Make-an-Animated-Ionic-Splash-Page-with-HTML-&-CSS)

But neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

did you install the native plugin for splashScreen ? 
if no follow this steps :
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen`
`npm install --save @ionic-native/splash-screen@4`

after import : 
`import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';`
constructor(private splashScreen: SplashScreen) { }

you can use the `this.splashScreen.hide();`

Comment: as you can see that I have done in splash.ts file above